# Where to get comparing list of papervision3d vs Away3d?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, papervision3d, away3d

So I know that PV3d looks quite dead. But it is documented over the internet much better. So I decided to develope my product using old but good PV3d engine. Time goes on so I plan to port it sooner or later to Away3d. So I need a list of things that aere not in Away3d that I have in PV3d. And a list of generall use diffrencies (use of cameras, viewports, etc). So where to get comparing list of papervision3d vs Away3d, or could any one please write it down here?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against this. Away3d was a fork of PV3D and there are a lot of similarities, but it looks like pv3d is dead, while we know for sure that Away3d is working on the molehill beta to create the new version. Once that comes out you might be wishing you would have gone with Away3d. There is also Alternativa and flare3D that are also working with molehill, but away3d is easier to start if you've worked with PV3d

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2310

anyway, that's my $0.02