# Is papervision 3d development alive?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, papervision3d

So I wonder if papervision 3d development alive? Any google code or ght..?

Comment: I wouldn't say 'dead', as in completely dead, but frozen to say the least. Carlos Ulloa, the original papervision developer left the project some time ago, Ralph Hauwert deloper working on the graphics engine left too. Lately I've seen just some minor fixes from Tim Knip and Seb Lee Delisle. There's isnt' a lot activity with this project at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: @George Profenza "Lately"? Where this fixes can be obtained?

Comment: "Lately" - april this year = http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/source/list Also there's a Papervision 3D 3.0 repository on github(https://github.com/Papervision3DTeam/Papervision3D), but there's not a lot of activity. The 3.0 version should use Flash Player 10 new drawing API and there's a fp10 branch in the googlecode repository, but personally I haven't them. HTH

Comment: Yep - I see... So my only hope is that someone will help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480372/where-to-get-comparing-list-of-papervision3d-vs-away3d and it would be clear for me how to do particle fields and vector 3d point clouds (where points are not resizable like here http://lab.zupko.info/pixels/ ) and I would port my virtual collider away (to away3d=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=papervisiom

site:

http://blog.papervision3d.org/

download:

http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/downloads/list

dev:

http://dev.papervision3d.org/

tutorials:

http://pv3d.org/

docs:

http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/index.html

Comment: But is development alive or not?